# Angular 2 input element databinding. How to use value of an input in a component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to be able to type into the input element and be able to use what is being typed in my component. I can't figure out how to do this. Once I have the value of the input elements I'll be using an event emitter to talk to the parent component.

If I could figure out how to get a method called whenever something is typed and get what is being typed this would solve my problem. I want the analystSettings I get as @Input to be updated whenever something is typed.

If an update to the analystSettings causes the parent components analystSettings to be update that would be awesome too.

this is my html:

```
<div style="margin: 2em;">
  <card>
    <h5>{{analystSetting.analyst}}</h5>
    <hr>
    <label>Alias</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="eg. John Smith"[value]="analystSetting.alias">

    <label>Percentage of principle</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="eg. 20" [value]="analystSetting.targetModifier * 100">

    <select>
    <option [attr.selected]="analystSetting.active?true:null">Active</option>
    <option [attr.selected]="!analystSetting.active?true:null">Disabled</option>
   </select>
   <button (click)="onSaveClicked()">Save</button>
   </card>
 </div>
```

this is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
import { AnalystSetting } from './AnalystSetting';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-analyst-settings',
  templateUrl: 'analyst-settings.component.html'
})
export class AnalystSettingsComponent {
  @Input() analystSetting: AnalystSetting;
  @Output() updatedAnalyst: EventEmitter<Object> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngModel`

```
<input type="text" placeholder="eg. John Smith"[(ngModel)]="analystSetting.alias" name="name">
```

You need to import the `FormsModule`

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

If Angular tries to render your input before `analystSetting` is set you might get an error in the console about `null` doesn't have a property `alias`.

You can wrap your form like `<card *ngIf="analystSetting">` to delay form rendering until `analystSetting` is available.

Comment: Where do I import FormsModule? In my component? When I try to import into my component FormsModule doesn't exist on '@angular/forms'

Comment: You import it in every `NgModule({imports: [...])` where you have components that make use of it. `NgModule` is `>=RC.5` otherwise use `bootstrap(AppComponent, [disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms()])`

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your input to HTML keypress event and handle it in your component as the following example provides:

```
<input type=text (keypress)="eventHandler($event)">

eventHandler(event) {
   console.log(event, event.keyCode, event.keyIdentifier);
}
```

I hope that helps.